# How to call a Dataflow job written in Python(3.x) from Cloud Functions in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataflow

My goal is creating a mechanism that when a new file is uploaded into the Cloud Storage, it'll trigger a Cloud Function. Eventually, this Cloud function will trigger a Cloud Dataflow job.
I have a restriction that the Cloud Dataflow job should be written in Python, and the Cloud Function also should be in Python.
he problem I have been facing right now is, I cannot call Cloud Dataflow job from a Cloud Function.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can! Start by [packaging your Dataflow Job in a template](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates). There is some update to perform for reading the input values. This change only the job header/configuration, not the "real" processing

Then, [trigger your template with API Rest](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/running-templates#using-the-rest-api). There is no python library for that, but there is a answer [here with code example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52388627/using-python-to-run-a-google-dataflow-template)